# Can I require an attribute to be set in a mongodb collection? (not null)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Can I define a schema in mongodb which requires certain attributes to be set. Much like `NOT NULL` in SQL. If that is possible. What is the syntax for this?

I am using node.js and mongoose.
mongoose v3.6.15
mongodb v2.4.5

**Edit** 
The answer provided by Charles A is correct but looking through the documentation I found that in mongoose it is also possible to define a field as required in the schema defenition like this:

```
foo : {
    bar : { type : String, required : true }
}
```

Comment: which driver are you using? I know how to do it in java with spring.

Comment: @Jayz Answer in updated quiestion...

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson It would be better to add your own answer as a separate answer to this question and then accept that as using `required: true` is the best way to do this.

Comment: @JohnnyHK But I accepted Charles answer because I solved my problem. Only afterwards did I change it to another format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Mongoose, you can use a [validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) to check if a field has been set before you save it. As far as I know, there is no way of specifying on a Schema that a field is required, so it requires a little more boilerplate code.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone finding their way here, you can use 'required', such that:

```js
db.createCollection("person", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "name" ],
         properties: {
            name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can read more in the documentation, [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/document-schemas/).

Note, that an alternative approach is to use Mongodb by means of [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/), which allows specifying this directly at the field level:

```js
const person = new mongoose.Schema({
    name {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks AndreM. In addition, here is a link to the doc on schema required attribute mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#storeSubdocValidationError need to call `person.validateSync()` to act validation before saving it.

Answer (score 2):

For required fields use $AND in collection's validator with "$exists: true":

```
db.createCollection("foo", {
  validator: {
    $and: [ {"bar": {$type: "string", $exists: true}} ]
})
```

more info here
https://www.compose.com/articles/document-validation-in-mongodb-by-example/

Answer (score 0):

Check value is null or empty using validation, the `required` property check is undefined only:

```json
foo : {
    bar : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        validation: (val) => ((val !== null) && (!!val.trim()))
    }
}
```